# What happens if construction function returns new Func()

Tags: javascript, prototype

When I write

```
function abc() {
 return 3;
}

var t = new abc();
console.log(t); // abc {}
```

However when i do this

```
function a() {
  this.name = 'test';
}

function b() {
  this.age = 33;
  return new a();
}

var p = new b();
console.log(p); // a { name = 'test'}
```

So In first example, why does it return an object when return is actually returning a number. And when i do return new Func() .... i get the new Obj.. the returned value.

In one scenario i get returned value, in other the main obj.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

Comment: since that's behavior of `new` we are discussing, I find it's related. we don't need to agree on that.

Answer (score 1):

That's as per ES5.1 specification [13.2.2 [[Construct]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget)

Relevant part:

> 8. Let result be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal property of
>      F, providing obj as the this value and providing the argument list
>      passed into [[Construct]] as args.
> 9. If Type(result) is Object then return result.
> 10. Return obj.

The similar part from the ES2015: [9.2.2 [[Construct]] ( argumentsList, newTarget)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget)

> 11. Let result be OrdinaryCallEvaluateBody(F, argumentsList).
> 12. Remove from the execution context stack and restore
>       callerContext as the running execution context.
> 13. If result.[[type]] is return, then
>
>     - If Type(result.[[value]]) is Object, return NormalCompletion(result.[[value]]).
>     - If kind is "base", return NormalCompletion(thisArgument).
>     - If result.[[value]] is not undefined, throw a TypeError exception.

Thanks to [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) for the summary:

> In other words, if the constructor returns an object, `new` returns that object, otherwise it returns `this`

Comment: In other words, if the constructor returns an object, `new` returns that object, otherwise it returns `this`.

Answer (score 1):

This constructor is okay:

```
function foo() {
  // will set attribute on new object
  this.age = 33;
}
t = new foo;
Object.getPrototypeOf(t);  // foo
```

This one as well:

```
function bar() {
  // delegates construction to other method
  // object will not have prototype bar, but prototype baz
  return new baz();
}
t = new bar;
Object.getPrototypeOf(t);  // baz
```

But this constructor will not do what most people expect:

```
function b() {
  this.age = 33;
  // because you are returning a different object;
  // that other object will not have its .age attribute set
  // by the statements above.
  // object will not have prototype b, but prototype a
  return new a();
}
t = new b;
Object.getPrototypeOf(t);  // a
```

You could however do the following:

```
function b() {
  var o = new a();
  o.age = 33;
  // object will not have prototype b, but prototype a
  return o;
}
t = new b;
Object.getPrototypeOf(t);  // a
```